# Failure lately with tabbing in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, action

We have had many tests using Selenium and Chrome where we have to tab out of a field, sometimes just in general, but other times to verify that the next expected input box has the focus.

This has been working successfully until recently.  Here is an example:

```
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
```

However lately this has not been functioning.  The cursor stays in the same input box as if it were ignoring the tab.  We can get around it in some instances by clicking on some random location, but for tests where we have to verify the cursor is moving into the next field, this will not work.

I was wondering whether anyone else has this problem, or if anyone knows what is going on?  Selenium and Chrome are up to date.  We are running java with Eclipse.

Comment: "whether anyone else has this problem" nope. "if anyone knows what is going on?" How could we, based on the info you provided? Idea: check with the dev team: did they insert a keypress event handler which just happens to throw away the TAB-s?

Comment: @Tony could be upgrade in your application or your test artifacts versions . what is the error you get now? any js error?

Comment: Nothing added.  They would not add that because one of the tests requires TABs and it works manually when you hit the TAB.  As a matter of fact when I am running the automation and it is stuck in a box, if I hit TAB it will move to the next box.  Our main SQA person is having the same problem.  I have not seen any Javascript error.  We are going to see whether the problem still exists after the next deployment.

Comment: Try once with Robot class..